# BootStrap how can in reverse div's order?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Bootstrap and i have a six columns contact form, when I'm looking it on my smartphone i see the button on top, or in general i see the order in revers to what i need, this is the code:
i see samples of push,

```
<div class="row"> <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">.col-md-9 .col-md-push-3</div> <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">.col-md-3 .col-md-pull-9</div> </div>
```

but how to do it with six columns?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6" >div1</div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6" >div2</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6" >div3</div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6" >div4</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6" >div5</div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6" >div6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

how can i reverse the ordering

Comment: Why is all your style inline and not in .css files?

Comment: Its for development only' all will go out in production mode

Comment: Well, you gave your div a `rtl` direction (prefer CSS for that) so it probably shows the items right to left. Try removing it.

Comment: I did remove the rtl, it has no effect, i see samples of push,  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">.col-md-9 .col-md-push-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">.col-md-3 .col-md-pull-9</div>
</div> but how to do it with six columns?

Comment: Please create a minimal and isolated code example and preferably also a fiddle if you expect help with your code. As it stands you have a long chunk of code and are asking a a question about it - if you ask the same question about much less code which I'm sure is possible - you'll get an answer much faster.

Comment: I did the changes you suggested, it much simpler now, thanks

Comment: You put them in the order you want on mobile and push them and pull them on larger viewports. As of now, none of the answers below are correct. http://www.williamghelfi.com/blog/2013/06/09/bootstrap-3-the-new-grid-system-for-starters/ -- go to the ordering section

Comment: Thanks for editing your question to be simple and self contained - I'd answer it but I see you already have two answers. +1 and good luck.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/yumayo/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is much simpler when written with right way in Bootstrap.
Try the following snippet:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">div1</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">div2</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">div3</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">div4</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">div5</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">div6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When on medium size screen the divs will show in a single line, but when you go on small screen, then will stack up to show 3 divs in a row, when you go on extra small screen the divs will stack up to show only one in a row.

Try this and inform me, if you are able to achieve the right layout or not.

**Updated Code:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 visible-lg visible-md visible-sm">div1</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 visible-lg visible-md visible-sm">div2</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 visible-lg visible-md visible-sm">div3</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 visible-lg visible-md visible-sm">div4</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 visible-lg visible-md visible-sm">div5</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">div6</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 visible-xs">div5</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 visible-xs">div4</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 visible-xs">div3</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 visible-xs">div2</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 visible-xs">div1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can't reverse the order but you can use some extra `div`s to achieve this functionality. Lets take extra 5 `div`s below 6th div and put them in reverse order. These divs will only show up on mobile screen. At the same time hide the above 5 divs at mobile screen. So now on mobile screen you are seeing divs in reverse order.

Comment: You are absolutely right!, but now i need to revers the order of the divs so in small screen, div 6 will be on top and div5 will be second and so on, do you know how can i do it?

Comment: I can't think of any in-built option for this, but there is a trick you can use for this. Let me edit my answer for you.

Comment: @ShimonWiener - Check the answer now, I have updated with working answer.

Answer (score 0):

As users in comments said, please move your CSS to external .css file, that way it it easier to read and help,

Please use [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/) or similar so people can better understand your question.

Try removing dir=rtl from outer div,
also you might want to read about Twitter Bootstrap's [Helper Classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes)

This is a simple bootstrap grid example,
where on 'xs' screen each div will take 6 (1/2) of available space.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-6">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">.col-md-2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

see this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3uXE0AbcP2w13cVUVvfX?p=preview) for example

Comment: I edited the code and left with simple one, missing only the reference to bootstrao

Comment: Edited the answer, please look at the plunkr at the bottom.